# What if we start using Devanagari Script in password generation?

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection, change-password, devanagari

As of a research by using ***Devanagari Script*** in captcha, the security of that captcha is increased from **88% to 96%.** So why not to use ***Devanagari Script*** in password also?

Answer (score 0):

This does indeed work.

Many systems, especially many web-based platforms (since UTF-8 is the de-facto standard for web development), allow users to use extended scripts in passwords. This allows use of many different languages, and also emoji.

Such passwords are a little harder crack with current tools (due to limitations in the tools) - but not impossibly so.

And as a confirming data point for Devanagari specifically, a few passwords in the 2016 public LinkedIn leak were in Devanagari. And note that LinkedIn didn't have to explicitly support Devanagari in particular - they just had to support UTF-8 and properly hash the results.